# Is it possible to perform elasticsearch nested stats aggregation on a field defined by the parent aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, plot, statistics

I'm trying to do a query to generate a plot. My data index looks like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "mydata": {
        "properties": {
            "type": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
            "stamp": { "type": "date", "format": "date_hour_minute_second_millis" },
            "data": { "type": "object" }
        }
    }
```

Depending on the type, the data field will contain different objects, e.g.,

```
temperature_data = {
    "type": "temperature",
    "stamp": "2015-11-01T15:25:19.123",
    "data": {"temperature": 23.4, "variance": 0.0}
}
humidity_data = {
    "type": "humidity",
    "stamp": "2015-11-01T15:26:21.063",
    "data": {"humidity": 75.1, "variance": 0.0}
}
```

I'm trying to aggregate the data on buckets depending on their type, and then perform a date histogram to get the stats of each reading (temperature, humidity). My problem is how to set the field on the stats aggs since it changes with the type (for `"type": "temperature"` the field is `data.temperature` for example):

```
query = {
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"range" : {
                            "stamp" : {
                                "gt" : start_stamp,
                                "lt" : end_stamp
                            }
                        }}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "pathes": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "type"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "points": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "stamp",
                        "interval": interval
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "point_stats": {
                            "stats": {
                                "field": "data."+field???
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

*** UPDATE ***

As suggested I added a data-type.groovy file to config/scripts/, the file contains the following:

```
return doc['data.temperature'].value
```

Elasticsearch is able to compile the script:

```
[2015-11-02 19:50:32,651][INFO ][script] [Atum] compiling script file [/home/user/elasticsearch-1.7.0/config/scripts/data-type.groovy]
```

I updated the query to load the script file:

```
query = {
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"range" : {
                            "stamp" : {
                                "gt" : start_stamp,
                                "lt" : end_stamp
                            }
                        }}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "pathes": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "type"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "points": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "stamp",
                        "interval": interval
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "point_stats": {
                            "stats": {
                                "script": {"file": "data-type"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the query I get the following output:

```
{u'status': 400, u'error': u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], ... Parse Failure [Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [point_stats].]]; }]'}
```

There's only temperature data in the database, if I change "script": {"file": "data-type"} for "field": "data.temperature" the query works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to rename the `humidity` and `temperature` fields to something identical, like `value`, so you can simply aggregate on that field and you're good. You'd already know what kind of value it is since you know it from the `type` field.

```
"aggs": {
    "pathes": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "type"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "points": {
                "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "stamp",
                    "interval": interval
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "point_stats": {
                        "stats": {
                            "field": "data.value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second option is to use a `script` but that'd be less performant and less scalable if you were to add more type of data (pressure, etc)

```
"aggs": {
    "pathes": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "type"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "points": {
                "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "stamp",
                    "interval": interval
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "point_stats": {
                        "stats": {
                            "script": "return doc.type.value == 'temperature' ? doc['data.temperature'].value : doc['data.humidity'].value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that for this second option you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was trying to avoid using the same naming for the field that holds the actual scalar value, since different sensors will have different structures, som might not even have a scalar value. I will study both options, though I'll try to steer away from the custom script!

Comment: Oh I see. You could still have different field names but create another one with a scalar value (where that applies) that you could use just for aggregations.

Comment: Can you do the same with a script file, instead of using the in-line script?

Comment: Yes, definitely, you just need to put the script in a file inside the the `config/scripts/` folder, reference it with ["file": "script_name"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html#_script_8) and it will be loaded at startup time.

Comment: I've done script files previously, but this does not seem to be working. I added the data-type.groovy file to config/scripts/, and it's loaded by ES. All I have inside the file is return doc['data.temperature'].value. If I run the query with "stats": {"field": "data.temperature"} it works, if I change it to "stats": {"script": {"file": "data-type"}} I get an error Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [point_stats]. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add an update section in your question with the full agg spec you're using now?